# Storing data from java to cassandra

Tags: java, python, cassandra, cql

I am storing file data. I read the file though java and when ever i am storing the file data in cassandra it gives me this error.

> Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:115 no viable alternative at input 'PRIMARY' (...* from sensorkeyspace.sensortable WHERE [PRIMARY]...)

Here my query is here

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  IF NOT EXISTS sensorkeyspace.texttable AS select * from sensorkeyspace.sensortable WHERE PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try altering your WHERE clause to this:

```
WHERE sensor_id IS NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id)
```

If you get an error indicating that:

> No columns are defined for Materialized View other than primary key

Based on [CASSANDRA-13564](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13564):

> That error message implies you re-used only the partition key/primary key from the base as the partition key for your view (you had no extra clustering columns in your base primary key).

I get that message when I have a table with a simple PRIMARY KEY, and I try to create a view with that same, simple PRIMARY KEY.

For example, if I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.newtable (
  name text PRIMARY KEY,
  score float,
  value float,
  value2 blob);
```

This fails:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS 
  stackoverflow.newtable_view AS SELECT * FROM stackoverflow.newtable 
  WHERE name IS NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY (name);

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] 
message="No columns are defined for Materialized View other than primary key"
```

But this works for the same table:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS 
  stackoverflow.newtable_view AS SELECT * FROM stackoverflow.newtable 
  WHERE score IS NOT NULL AND name IS NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY (score,name);

Warnings :
Materialized views are experimental and are not recommended for production use.
```

Not really related, but do note that last part; about how using MVs in Cassandra really isn't a good idea, yet.

Comment: In that condition it gives me this error      "No columns are defined for Materialized View other than primary key"

Comment: Still it give me error  "No columns are defined for Materialized View other than primary key"

Comment: @Realtiger Can you edit your post to add your table definition?  It's hard to tell you why without it.